# How to connect Springboot to mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I wanna to count by record how much true, false and null have in that nested document , I look in documentation but can't understand

With this collection:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "day": "2019-01-01",
    "destinatarios": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "leitura": "2019-01-01",
        "respostas": [
          {
            "positiva": true
          },
          {
            "positiva": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "leitura": "2019-01-01",
        "respostas": [
          {
            "positiva": true
          },
          {
            "positiva": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "leitura": null,
        "respostas": []
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "leitura": "2018-01-01",
        "respostas": [
          {
            "positiva": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
  "id": "2",
  "day": "2019-01-01",
  "destinatarios": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "leitura": "2019-01-01",
      "respostas": [
        {
          "positiva": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "leitura": "2019-01-01",
      "respostas": [
        {
          "positiva": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "leitura": null,
      "respostas": [
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "leitura":null,
      "respostas": [
      ]
    }
    ]
}
]
```

it's possible to create this return:

Id  - positivos  - negativos - nao_responderam

1   -     4      -     1     -        1

2   -     2      -     0     -        2

Answer (score 0):

You're really asking 2 very different questions here:

1. How to write this aggregation query
2. How to represent / run the aggregation using Spring Boot

You will probably find many more people able to answer #1 than #2. I would also suggest that you approach the problem similarly, to get your aggregation working first in the mongo shell and then codify the aggregation pipeline into your application.

Since you have 2 nested arrays, you'll need to use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to unwind them so that you can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) to count based on your compound grouping of `id` and `respostas`.

Something like this should work:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {$unwind:"$destinatarios"},
  {$unwind:{path:"$destinatarios.respostas", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}},
  {$project:{_id:0,id:1,resp:{$ifNull:["$destinatarios.respostas.positiva", "null"]}}},
  {$group: {_id:{id:"$id", resp:"$resp"}, count: { $sum: 1 }}},
  {$sort:{"_id.id":1}},
  {$project:{_id:0,id:"$_id.id",resp:"$_id.resp",count:1}}
])
```

I would suggest that you run that aggregation adding one stage at a time to better understand what each stage is doing. It will make a lot more sense to understand it that way.

Regarding the second question of how to do this using Spring Boot (probably using Spring Data MongoDB), there are a few ways that it could be done. The [Spring Data MongoDB docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation) will provide details and examples on the fluent-like API that is provided.

One "trick" which you might want to consider for complex aggregations is to write the aggregation as plain JSON and then parse it. You could even put it in a file and read the pipeline from a file. Here's a basic example:

```
    String stage1Json = "{$unwind:\"$destinatarios\"}";
    Document stage1 = Document.parse(stage1Json);
    List<Document> pipeline = new ArrayList<Document>();
    pipeline.add(stage1);

    AggregateIterable<Document> results = template.getDb().getCollection("foo").aggregate(pipeline);
    for (Document result : results) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```